# Why indexing is paused and I do nothing

Tags: search-indexing

Often indexing is paused

I did nothing. I never told windows to pause indexing. Sometimes it works out by itself. Sometimes it doesn't

[image]

And how exactly I should turn it on?

By the way going to computer management and check indexing services show that it's running

[image]

So no idea why windows THINK that it's not running

Comment: Maybe it is paused because it has nothing left to index ar the moment and is just waiting.

Comment: You can determine if it's fully indexed the locations selected by opening the _Advanced_ settings and choosing to always index, instead of only when the machine is idle

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft article
[Troubleshoot Windows Search performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/shell-experience/windows-search-performance-issues)
lists three pause messages and reasons:

> - Indexing is paused to conserve battery power.
>   The Indexer has stopped adding new items to the index because of low battery power.
>   Search results may not be complete.
>   Connect the device to power, and
>   charge the battery. After the battery has sufficiently charged,
>   indexing resumes.
> - Your group policy is set to pause indexing while on battery power.
>   Your IT department has configured the Indexer pause while the device
>   uses battery power.
>   To finish indexing, connect the device to power.
>   Contact your IT team if you want to change the policy.
> - Indexing is paused.
>   The Indexer has been paused from the Windows Search settings page.
>   Indexing resumes 15 minutes after it pauses.
>   To resume indexing more quickly, restart the Windows Search service
>   (`wsearch`). You can do it by using the Services tab of Task Manager
>   or by using `Services.msc`.

Your image seems to indicate the last case, caused apparently
by some interface with Windows Search. In this case, indexing
is supposed resume automatically in a few minutes.

If you suspect a more serious problem,
check that Windows Search is running in `services.msc`,
and you may also run the Search and Indexing troubleshooter
from:

- Windows 10 :
  *Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot >
  Additional troubleshooters*
- Windows 11 :
  *Settings > System > Troubleshoot > Other troubleshooters*.